# Relative clause with genitive and plural

Tags: grammaticality, relative-pronouns

I am a non-native speaker and for this very special example I can't find any explicit rules in the literature:

> The paths, *whose* lengths are equal, have been created.

Is "whose" the right word here? I can only find singular examples and wonder if the word must change for plurals.

Comment: Whose is fine but you can also use "The paths, the lengths of which are..." There are multiple options but I wouldn't say one is better.

Comment: _Whose_ is both singular and plural, like _who_. And, as the only possessive _wh_-word, it can refer to people, places, things, and ideas.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, but most inconsiderately and unhelpfully, it is one of those *wh*-words which seems to prove that interrogative and relative *wh*-words are different beasts. We have a gap in our interrogative *wh*-word arsenal, as we have no possessive *wh*-word that can refer to inanimate objects. We can say *The car whose wheel fell off*, but in *Whose wheel fell off?*, the word *whose* must refer to people or a person (or other animate being(s)). It couldn't mean *which car's*, for example.

Comment: @Araucaria-Him Interesting. Would that be about the same level of irregularity as the inability of _what_ and  _how_  as relative pronouns?

Comment: @JohnLawler Seems like it. There's gaps on both sides. Need to get in touch with the design team.

Comment: @Araucaria. That's an interesting observation. The question "_Whose car was parked in your spot?_" has a genitive answer. Eg. _John's_. But there seems to be no way to ask a similar question  whose answer would be "_a car's_"? A gap indeed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Whose* is the relative pronoun for both singular and plural antecedents and in both restrictive (defining) and non-restrictive (non-defining, supplemental) relative clauses. So the sentence "*The paths, whose lengths are equal, have been created*", with its plural antecedent and non-restrictive relative clause, is grammatical.

*Cambridge Grammar of English* by Carter and McCarthy has two examples of *whose* whose antecedents are plural noun phrases (page 387).

> *Whose* is not restricted to people. Animals and things can also be
> referred to:
>
> - Koalas, **whose** nocturnal habits are well-known, are unique to Australia.
> - Those are the cars **whose** windows got broken.

Comment: Are you really using that book? Surely not!

Comment: @BillJ. The CGoE is a prescriptive grammar for language learners. Most of the examples in the book are drawn from the _Cambridge International Corpus_. Its terminology and classification may differ in some cases from H&P's authoritative descriptive grammar. But its content is comprehensive and appropriate for English learners. Please let me know if there is anything in my answer that is questionable.

Comment: +1 And I think it's fine to use CGoL for various bits and bobs, most certainly for finding attested examples. Huddleston himself said so, even though he eviscerated it's grammar - mainly along the lines  of it being completely inconsistent with itself. However, there's no doubt that CGoE's meant to be descriptive. CGoE p. 6: "The main approach taken in this book is descriptive". (Of course, like CaGEL, CGoE alerts students to what prescriptivists like to pronounce).

Comment: @Araucaria. Yes, "_prescriptive_" was the wrong word. The CGoE is a pedagogic grammar for non-native learners of English. I like the fact that it gives a lot of attention to spoken language, uses mainly authentic examples and includes a section on _Information Packaging_, which is not always covered in other pedagogic grammars.

Comment: Note for NNS users. Interrogative *whose* does not follow the same pattern. It cannot be used for inanimate objects and is only used for animate beings (people, animals, ghosts, animate objects in films and stories and so on).